# Migration from SVN to git using Git-SVN

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I am trying to migrate a repository from SVN to git using Git-SVN.  The problem is i only want to migrate some folders in the trunk but no branches and no tags.  i am using "git svn fetch" command to first fetch the files i want to migrate.  My SVN repository is something like this:

https://svn.myexamplerepo.com/

trunk/MyProject/

```
 |-FolderA
 |-FolderB
   |-SubFolderB1
   |-SubFolderB2
     |-SubSubFolderB2X
     |-SubSubFolderB2Y
   |-SubFolder3
 |-FolderC     
 |-File1.txt
 |-File2.txt
```

I only want to fetch

```
trunk/MyProject/FolderA
trunk/MyProject/FolderB/SubFolderB2/SubSubFolderB2Y
trunk/MyProject/File1.txt
```

But i am having a hard time figuring out how to do this.  I have tried modifying my git config file to:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[svn-remote "FolderA"]
    url = https://svn.myexamplerepo.com/
    fetch = trunk/FolderA:refs/remotes/origin/FolderA
[svn-remote "SubFolderB2Y"]
    url = https://svn.myexamplerepo.com/
    fetch =trunk/FolderB/SubFolderB2/SubSubFolderB2Y:refs/remotes/origin/SubFolderB2Y
[svn-remote "File1"]
    url = https://svn.myexamplerepo.com/
    fetch = trunk/File1.txt:refs/remotes/origin/File1
[svn]
    authorsfile = C:/MyMigration/authors.txt
```

But this does not work.  I only get File1.txt or sometimes nothing at all.  What am i doing wrong or is there a better way of doing this?  I have looked at some of the other questions but none seem to answer this question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.git/config` file can’t achieve the goal. You can use `git svn clone` separately to clone different folders/file into git repositories, and then combine the git repositories together. Detail steps as below:

**1.Clone FolderA**

```
# In a directory (such as d:\repos)
git svn clone https://svn.myexamplerepo.com/trunk/MyProject/FolderA
cd FolderA
mkdir FolderA
mv * FolderA
git add .
git commit -m 'move to FolderA'
```

**2.Clone SubSubFolderB2Y**

```
# In a directory (such as d:\repos)
git svn clone https://svn.myexamplerepo.com/trunk/MyProject/FolderB/SubFolderB2/SubSubFolderB2Y
cd SubSubFolderB2Y
mkdir SubSubFolderB2Y
mv * SubSubFolderB2Y
git add .
git commit -m 'move to SubSubFolderB2Y'
```

**3.Clone File1.txt**

```
# In a directory (such as d:\repos)
git svn clone https://svn.myexamplerepo.com/trunk/MyProject
cd MyProject
#delete all the files and folder except File1.txt
git commit -am 'keep File1.txt'
```

**4.Combine all the git repositories together**

```
# in FolderA directory (d:\repos\FolderA)
git remote add subB d:/repos/SubSubFolderB2Y
git remote add file d:/repos/MyProject
git pull subB master --allow-unrelated-histories
git pull file master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Now the git repo in `d:\repos\FolderA` is what you want, it contains:

```
FolderA
SubSubFolderB2Y
File1.txt
```

Comment: git svn init + git svn fetch is the same as git svn clone.  Yes i can also clone my repo without branches or tags by just using git svn clone and --trunck =... without --branches and --tags but that does not help in cloning only specific folders in the trunck.

Comment: Ok, since you want to use git -svn, I updated my answer with the way to use git-svn. You can have a try.

Comment: Thanks, this method works so i will give you credit for the answer.  However i figured out an easier way of doing what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way of doing this by adding --include-paths or --ignore-paths.  So for example using--include-paths:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    include-paths = FolderA|FolderB/SubFolderB2/SubSubFolderB2Y|File1.txt
    url = https://svn.myexamplerepo.com/
    fetch = MyProject:refs/remotes/trunk
[svn]
    authorsfile = C:/MyMigration/authors.txt
```

When using --ignore-paths then list the paths you do not want cloned.

So to do a clone using svn git clone:

```
git svn clone --trunk="/FolderA" --include-paths="FolderA|FolderB/SubFolderB2/SubSubFolderB2Y|File1.txt" --authors-file=authors.txt "https://svn.myexamplerepo.com/" "./MyGitFolder"
```